# Set first week of the year from the first day of the year until the following monday

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I want that Oracle treats weeks the following way:

-The week starts on monday 
-The first week of the year is from the first day of the year until the following monday

So for 2015 would be

01-jan-2015 (Thursday)  would be 1 
02-jan-2015 (Friday)  would be 1 
03-jan-2015 (Saturday) would be 1 
04-jan-2015 (Sunday) would be 1 
05-jan-2015 (Monday) would be 2 
06-jan-2015 (Tuesday) would be 2

For 2017 would be

01-jan-2017 (Sunday)  would be 1 
02-jan-2017 (Monday)  would be 2 
03-jan-2017 (Tuesday) would be 2 
04-jan-2017 (Wednesday) would be 2

and so on....

I need the numeration for the year so would go to 1 to 53-54

Comment: You can do this with date arithmetic, but I'd rather use a calendar table.

Comment: Do you need a partial first week? Or may it contain the last days of the preceding year? i.e.: week 1 is from 1 jan 2014 to 5 jan 2014 _or_ from 30 dec 2013 to 5 jan 2014?

Comment: dont really care wether it contains the days of previous year as long as the two conditions i mention are met

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit of arithmetics will probably do the trick (assuming `d` is your date):

```
select TRUNC((case to_char(d, 'DY')
          when 'MON' then 6
          when 'TUE' then 5
          when 'WED' then 4
          when 'THU' then 3
          when 'FRI' then 2
          when 'SAT' then 1
          when 'SUN' then 0
       end + to_number(to_char(d, 'DDD'))-1) / 7)+1
from v;
```

- The `case` statement will build an offset according to the day of week
- next I add the day of year
- then I divide the result by 7 for the week number (starting at 0)
- finally, the +1 will start numbering weeks at 1

Please take some time to experiment with it http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/38236 to check if I didn't make a stupid mistake as I didn't have time to test it thoughtfully. Sorry about that...

Answer (score 1):

Use the ISO week date standard: 'iw'.

2014-01-01 was Wednesday actually, so:

```
select
  to_number(to_char(date'2014-01-05', 'iw')) as weeknum, 
  to_char(date'2014-01-05', 'Day') as day
from dual;

    WEEKNUM DAY
----------- ---------
          1 Sunday

select
  to_number(to_char(date'2014-01-06', 'iw')) as weeknum,
  to_char(date'2014-01-06', 'Day') as day
from dual;

    WEEKNUM DAY
----------- ---------
          2 Monday
```

Comment: I query that for 2-jan-2017 which is monday, would give me as weeknum 1 so not good, i would like a 2 as a result